# requires that 'moveView' conform to 'StringProtocol' in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a struct to pass the `ObservedObject` value change.

```
struct moveView : View {

    @Binding var move : Bool

    var body: some View {
        if move{
           return Text("1")
        }else{
           return Text("2")
        }
    }
}
struct TextView : View {

    @ObservedObject var skc:xiangcene

    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
         .opacity(moveView(move: $skc.move) == "1" ? 0.1 : 0.8) // <- error on this line
    }
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

> Referencing operator function `==` on `StringProtocol` requires that `moveView` conform to `StringProtocol`

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your struct is of type 'View' and you are comparing it to a 'String' constant.

You could check the boolean value:

```
.opacity(moveView(move: $skc.move).move ? 0.1 : 0.8)
```

But using the expression:

```
moveView(move: $skc.move)
```

does not make sense here. You are creating a new view here with the value of the variable.

Better:

```
.opacity( skc.move ? 0.1 : 0.8)
```